# Magento : How to Add City List in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I want to add city list in magento database and use that list in dropdown of custom module. How Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't store cities anywhere by default. The only way to do this is by using a third party webservices which can support you with all the cities in the world, or by creating a new extension, which adds this functionality.

For the functionality within the frontend, you could look at the way Magento implements the countries, which is kind of the same idea.

Another option, is that you implement some kind of postcode/zipcode lookup. In The Netherlands this is pretty common. A user enters his postcode and house number and a third party webservice provides you with the city and streetname. I'm not sure if this is available in India or worldwide, but it might be worth it to check it.

Comment: i want to add city manually.

Comment: is there is any option to add city list in existing city field. and use these in custom module?

Comment: You can create an extension, create a database table containing the city names and load those into your template in a selectbox.

Comment: if i create new table with city field it will be duplicate of existing city field in magento. i want to use existing city field of magento which are already in magento database.

Comment: You can't use the existing field in that way. At least you need to replace it with a selectbox with the same name. As far as I know, cities aren't stored in Magento, only the ones entered by your customers in the past.